# How to access json value after convert string to json

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to convert list of strings contain sentences such as:

```
my_string=u'[{"id":1275829555,"guid":11}, {"id":1275829512,"guid" :12 }]'
```

and want to convert it into the following json type:

```
[
 {
    "id":1275829555,
    "guid":11
 },
 {
    "id":1275829555,
    "guid":12
 }
]
```

unfortunately I can not access json

```
print type(my_string) # <type 'unicode'>
json_string =  str( json.dumps(my_string, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8') )
print type(json_string) # <type 'str'>
j_obj = json.loads(json_string)
print type(j_obj) # <type 'unicode'>
print j_obj[0] 
[
```

how can I access json to handle each entry in the array ?

Comment: What you have is both the same JSON string, the only difference is the formatting or more exactly the indentation.

Comment: like that:  **j_obj[0]["id"] = 3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, doing

```
my_string=u'[{"id":1275829555,"guid":11}, {"id":1275829512,"guid" :12 }]'
j_obj = json.loads(my_string)
j_obj[0]
```

prints

```
{'guid': 11, 'id': 1275829555}
```

So I'm thinking there's something with your `json_string =  str( json.dumps(my_string, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8') )` that screws you over

Answer (score 3):

Hi you did everything correct, you just need a string instead of a unicode

```
import json
import unicodedata

my_string=u'[{"id":1275829555,"guid":11}, {"id":1275829512,"guid" :12 }]'

my_string = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', my_string).encode('ascii','ignore')
print type(my_string) # <type 'unicode'>
print my_string
print type(json_string) # <type 'str'>
j_obj = json.loads(str(a))
print type(j_obj) # <type 'unicode'>
print j_obj[0]["id"]
```

Comment: at line json.loads happening something strange:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))

Comment: You are getting **\x00** as you probably have Null Values

Comment: yes , will try first of all to eliminate all Null Values

Answer (score 1):

json.dumps serializes a python object into a string and json.loads deserializes a string to a python object.  You pass a string into dumps, which is going to serialize that string into another string.  I think what you want is just to just my_string as json_string.

```
>>> import json
>>> json_string = u'[{"id":1275829555,"guid":11}, {"id":1275829512,"guid" :12 }]'
>>> print json.dumps(json_string, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')  # No op.  Just displaying string serialized to another string.
"[{\"id\":1275829555,\"guid\":11}, {\"id\":1275829512,\"guid\" :12 }]"

>>> j_obj = json.loads(json_string)
>>> print j_obj
[{u'guid': 11, u'id': 1275829555}, {u'guid': 12, u'id': 1275829512}]

>>> print j_obj[0]
{u'guid': 11, u'id': 1275829555}
```